# Creating Downloadable concern in Rails 4: Error with send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, module, mixins

I'm trying to create a Downloadable concern with Rails 4.0.4 that I can mix in to all of my downloadable resources. Let's use the Documents resource as an example of something that should be downloadable:

```
#documents_controller.rb
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  include Downloadable
  before_action :set_document

  #Other actions....

  #Download
  def download
    send @document.document_full_path
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_document
      @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

The Downloadable module looks like (simple for now, but I want to add some validation code to check if the file actually exists and is readable, plus stream it and/or use x-file, etc):

```
#app/controller/concerns/downloadable
module Downloadable extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def send(filepath)
    send_file filepath
  end

end
```

And in my routes I have defined a downloadable concern:

```
#routes.rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  concern :downloadable do
    get 'download', on: :member
  end

  resources :documents, concerns: :downloadable

  root 'welcome#index'

end
```

When I spin up my puma server and try to go to 0.0.0.0:3000/documents/ I get an error:

```
ActionController::MissingFile in DocumentsController#index
Cannot read file _process_action_callbacks

Extracted source (around line #4):  

3    def send(filepath) 
4      send_file filepath 
5    end

app/controllers/concerns/downloadable.rb:4:in `send'
```

Before refactoring this as a concern I had it working using send_file(@document.document_full_path) directly in the 'download' method of the DocumentsController. I didn't get any errors until I refactored it as a concern in the controller and in routes.rb. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was namespace pollution; the 'send' method did not resolve to my Downloadable module. I'm not exactly sure where it did resolve but in the end all I did was rename the method to 'send_to_user'. I also could have fixed it by making the call with the scope explicitly resolved 'Downloadable::send', but I think this this syntax is less sugary than just renaming the method.

After this change my Downloadable concern looks like:

```
module Downloadable extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def send_to_user(args={})
    send_file args[:filepath]
  end

end
```

And in my documents controller I have:

```
#documents_controller.rb
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  include Downloadable
  before_action :set_document

  #Other actions....

  #Download
  def download
    send_to_user filepath: @document.document_full_path
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_document
      @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

routes.rb is the same as above.